Books/Articles related to profit protection?
Anyone have any advanced book/article recommendations related to profit protection or adjusting open positions to maximize profits once a position is taken? I only have a cs degree but have read books of Mark Minervini or Stefan's Machine Learning for Algorithmic Trading where they talk about profit protection and adjusting positions briefly but never really found anything that would dig deeper into the topic.
Thanks

"Profit protection" sounds like a fancy term for Trailing Stops. You get out if the drawdown exceeds a predetermined amount, stay in the trade otherwise. It is a common strategy that is part of the folklore of trading but I have never seen a careful scientific evaluation.

Yeah, I've seen various ways to lock in profits. Using volatility, breakeven risk, risk adjusted stop losses. But no definition on what is better.

You should also look at the Doob Optional Stopping Theorem, which shows that for a Martingale Process, stopping early does not change the expectation. You avoid losses, but you also avoid gains that you could have made by continuing. It can reduce variance but so can taking a smaller position to begin with. This kind of Null Result suggest we need a (maybe theoretical? empirical? behavioral?) justification why Profit Protection techniques "work" and how they work.

What they are probably talking about is what was called in the 80s as portfolio insurance you hedge your portfolio in times of rising unease with put options. Generally you match your portfolio of shares with put options at some point before your acquisition price, generally 5% of your portfolio is spent on out of the money puts that in times of distress quickly become in the money. Stops are not insurance they are a mechanism by which you exit a trade at a set point, to preserve profit, but in rapidly falling markets stops don't hold long enough to sell out and get out. Stops and stop limits are no good for crashes or big drawdowns.I am a quant and have read all this advanced math stuff and much is good but from all the stuff I have read lately here, people are divorced from the reality of real physical trading, just because you have a computer and an amazing formula does not alter market realities.Stopping time rules are highly theoretical, I use Shiryaev Roberts stopping time procedures from statistical process control. it is a real thing which addresses real risks, not mathematical abstraction.See William Ziembas book on Stock market crashes predictable and unpredictable.
